# Making GridView Vertically Scrollable

Tags: asp.net, gridview

In my ASP.net program, I'm trying to make my gridview have a scrollbar whenever the data doesn't fit in the div. I've looked around and found answers but none of them work, what am I doing wrong? Here's my code, and I've tried changing `overflow: scroll` to `overflow: auto` and that hasn't worked either - thanks.

```
 <div style="width: 100%; height: 200px; overflow:scroll;">
<asp:GridView ID="usersGridView" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 10px; top: 231px; position: absolute; height: 133px; width: 352px" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#336666" BorderStyle="Double" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" GridLines="Horizontal">
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
<Columns>
    <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" HeaderText="Edit" ShowEditButton="True" >
    <ControlStyle BackColor="#336666" ForeColor="White" />
    </asp:CommandField>
</Columns>
<FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#336666" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
<PagerStyle BackColor="#336666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
<RowStyle BackColor="#d6ded9" ForeColor="#333333" />
<SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#339966" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
<SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
<SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#487575" />
<SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E5E5E5" />
<SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#275353" />
</asp:GridView>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 200px; overflow-y:scroll;">
```